# Javascript: How to loop through document and change a few words?

Tags: javascript, html, firefox-addon

I'm doing this just to learn a bit about Firefox plugins and Javascript. I'm new to Javascript and FF plugins. I've been Googling for 2 hours, read about 30 different pages on the subject, but no page really matches what I'm trying to do. If you didn't guess, I learn best by looking at code.

Not using Jquery, just raw Javascript. I might get to Jquery later, but not now.

I'd like to loop through certain elements on a web page, like a, p, div, and change any words in their displayed html (.innerHTML). But I'm having problems. Here's my code.

```
// Change the text in these elements.
var eleArr=['a', 'p', 'h1', 'h2', 'blockquote', 'div', 'td', 'li'];
var fromArr=['men', 'man', 'Men', 'Man', 'guy', 'guys', 'girl', 'Girl'];
var toArr=['Blues', 'Blue', 'Blues', 'Blue', 'blue', 'blues', 'pink', 'pink'];
var i;

console.log("Starting, eleArr.length="+eleArr.length);

// First loop through every element to check for string in fromArr[].
for (i=0; i < eleArr.length; i++)
  {
  //console.log("Checking element "+eleArr[i]);
  test1(eleArr[i]); // Process one element at a time.
  }


////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
function test1(mytag)
{
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName(mytag);
var i, j;

console.log("Test1: Checking element '"+mytag+"'");

for (i=0; i<elements.length; i++) // Loop through all elements with mytag.
  {
    // Loop through fromArr[] here.
    for (j=0; j<fromArr.length; j++)
      {
      var s=fromArr[j];
      var re=/s/ig; // Creates regex object.
      var ele=elements[i];
      var oldhtml=ele.innerHTML;
      if (oldhtml.indexOf(fromArr[j]) >= 0)
        {
          console.log("TEST1: Found: "+fromArr[j]+" in ele '"+mytag+"': "+oldhtml);
        oldhtml.replace(re, toArr[j]);
        ele.innerHTML=oldhtml;
          console.log("TEST1: Replaced with: "+oldhtml)
        }
      }
  }
}
```

The first element it finds is a  element, but it has tons of child elements in the ele.innerHTML. How do I grab just the displayed HTML text? Example of first element grabbed.

```
<div>
<p class="parent"></p>
<a href="http://www.some.com">some link</a>. 
</div>
```

Technically, the  element does not have any displayable text to change. But the 'a' anchor element does have text to look at which is 'some link'.

What am I doing wrong here?

Thank you.

Comment: I would suggest a recursive function that you should pass your `elements[i]` if it passes the test

Comment: Seems you found a solution, but here is how I would do it: http://jsfiddle.net/7hrs9tsg/

Comment: Thanks. I ran your test. But change the link text to 'man guy has good manners' and it comes out 'blue blue has good blueners'. I only want whole words changed, not words that contain 'man' plus other text. Any idea how to fix that? I've been playing with some things but haven't gotten it to work yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer here. The problem was how I was processing the elements.

http://commons.oreilly.com/wiki/index.php/Greasemonkey_Hacks/Beautifying_the_Web#Straighten_Smart_Quotes

Now I have the basic way to do this I'm having another problem. When I change 'man' to 'blue' I only want to change whole words, but it isn't working. I'm not sure what the regex would be to do this.

INPUT: Many a man has good manners man.

CURRENT OUTPUT: Bluey a blue has good blueners blue.

EXPECTED OUTPUT: Many a blue has good manners blue.

Notes:

- [Cannot do .replace on .innerHTML.](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/replacing-text-in-the-dom-solved/) Why it's not as easy as it seems.
- [Same guy above has a solution which works in most cases.](https://github.com/padolsey/findAndReplaceDOMText)

Comment: I think theres a more efficient way, to use DOMTreeWalker: https://discourse.mozilla-community.org/t/my-addon-has-been-rejected-need-some-info-to-fix-it/3812

Comment: If you have another question about [regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) you should ask ([ask]) it as a separate question. However, for your specific regular expression, you might want to try something like `/\bman\b/` as `\b` is the [special character](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Using_special_characters) that is used to indicate a word boundary.